# Passport-Facebook works in localhost but not in Heroku (MERN Stack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm making a simple app with Facebook login. It works perfectly fine in localhost. However, after deploying to Heroku, the Login button just refreshes the page and the browser stays on `https://voting-app-28.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook` without redirecting. I have tried everything and have added the URL to the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs on facebook as well. There are no errors in the console.

my passport.js

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => done(null, user));
});

passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.facebookClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.facebookClientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
      profileFields: ['id', 'name'],
      proxy: true
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      User.findOne({ facebookId: profile.id }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          new User({ facebookId: profile.id })
            .save()
            .then(user => done(null, user));
        }
      });
    }
  )
);
```

my authRoutes.js

```
  app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

  app.get(
    '/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook'),
    (req, res) => {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  );
```

Here is my [Github repo](https://github.com/c-clin/voting-app) and the [Heroku app](https://voting-app-28.herokuapp.com/) so you can see what I mean.

Please help and thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After many Google searches I discovered that Facebook will only allow requests from HTTPS. Even though my Heroku domain was HTTPS it did not have an ssl certificate. I upgraded to a hobby dyno and applied an ssl cert in the settings on Heroku and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and it turns out that it's a proxy issue. I added this to my app.ts and it fixed it: `app.enable('trust proxy')`